# "unknown partition table" - misconfigured kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, partition, grub2, ext4

I was compiling a custom linux kernel for a newly installed machine, and after booting into the new kernel (3.12), the init process fails to find a root device, which I traced to the system getting an `unknown partition table` error on the device in question (`/dev/sda`). The generic kernel boots up and mounts the root partition just fine. I cannot seem to find anything that looks relevant in the kernel config, what could it be missing?

Comment: What type of partition table does it have?

Comment: It's a good old fashioned MBR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of options mostly named `CONFIG_.*_PARTITION`, you probably didn't set the one you need. These may only show up if you answer yes to `CONFIG_PARTITION_ADVANCED` (Advanced partition selection).

You're going to want (on a PC) at least:

```
CONFIG_MSDOS_PARTITION=y       # traditional MS-DOS partition table
CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION=y         # EFI GPT partition table
```

and maybe:

```
LDM_PARTITION=y                # Windows logical (dynamic) disks
```

You may also want a few more (such as `CONFIG_MAC_PARTITION` and `BSD_DISKLABEL`) to read partition tables from other operating systems' disks you may actually run in to.

You can see all of the partition table options in your kernel source tree (in `block/partitions/Kconfig`) or at [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12.6/block/partitions/Kconfig).